# Form tag messing up my site

Tags: html, css, forms

I am working on my website and when I add the form tag it messes up my navigation bar. I have tried giving it 0 padding 0 margin and it doesn't seem to help.

http://pyxel.atspace.tv is how the navbar is supposed to be, but http://pyxel.atspace.tv/contact.php is how it ends up.

Here is what the form is in just in the middle of the site. Nothing in it or anything:

```
<div class="middlecontents">
    <form>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the css I have for all the tags (I don't have a css for the form itself):

```
* {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;    
    -ms-user-select: none;      
    user-select: none;
}
```

Here is my navbar (Nothing special just a lot of divs):

```
<div id="navbar">
    <!-- Orange bar in Navbar-->
    <div id="topbar"></div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <!--Home button-->
        <a href="/">
            <p class="button">Home</p>
        </a>
        <!--Divider-->
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <!--About us button-->
        <a href="about.php"><p class="dbutton">About<br>Us</p></a>
        <!--Divider-->
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <!--Forums Button-->
        <a href="forums.php">
            <p class="button">Forums</p>
        </a>
        <!--Divider-->
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <!--Contacct Button-->
        <a href="contact.php">
            <p class="button">Contact</p>
        </a>
        <!--Divider-->
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <!--Information Button-->
        <a href="info.php">
            <p class="dbutton">Donate/Vote<br>Information</p>
        </a>
        <!--Divider-->
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <!--Donate Button-->
        <a href="donate.php">
            <p class="button">Donate</p>
        </a>
        <!--Divider-->
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <!--Vote Button-->
        <a href="vote.php">
            <p class="button">Vote</p>
        </a>
        <!--Divider-->
    </div>
    <div id="profile">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="topborder"></div>
```

If it shows the navbar as it does on the home page refresh it a few times. Very strange how it works.

Comment: The navigation bar looks exactly the same in both those links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why that is happening but you can fix withL

```
#buttons {
  float: left;
  height: 61px;
  width: 100%;
}
```